# Android sqlite insert method is working in emulator but not in device

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to insert the the data to database, it is working in emulator, but when I try to work on device , It is not inserting data.

### Db helper class

```
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class DataBaseHelper {

    SQLiteDatabase dbe;

    public DataBaseHelper(Context mycontext, String getPackageName) {

        copyDB(mycontext, getPackageName);// This method helps to copy the database from asserts to mobile

    }

    void copyDB(Context mycontext, String getPackageName) {
        try {

            String destPath = "data/data/" + getPackageName + "/databases";//this is the path for the database to save

            Log.v("opendb", "destPath: " + destPath);

            File f3 = new File(destPath);// initiating new file in destination path
            if (!f3.exists()) {         // this loop helps to create file if the file if does't not exist
                Boolean flag = f3.mkdir();
                Log.v("opendb", "mkdir flag: " + flag);

                destPath = destPath + "/AuditDb.sqlite";//It gives the destination path to copy the sqlite file from assert
                File f2 = new File(destPath);
                if (!f2.exists()) {
                    Log.v("opendb", "File Not Exist");
                    flag = f2.createNewFile();
                    Log.v("opendb", "create file flag: " + flag);
                }

                AssetManager assetManager = mycontext.getAssets();// getting the path of actual saved in asserts

                String[] files = null;

                files = assetManager.list("");// listing all files in assert 

                for (String filename : files) {// choosing the database file among other files
                    Log.i("opendb", filename);
                    InputStream in = null;  // to take stream of values from Source file
                    OutputStream out = null;    //  to write the value from source to destination file

                    if (filename.equals("HealthDb.sqlite")) {
                        in = assetManager.open(filename);
                        Log.i("opendb", filename + " opened Successfully");
                        out = new FileOutputStream(destPath);
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int length;
                        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
                        }
                        in.close();// terminating inputstream
                        out.close();// terminating outputstream
                    }
                }
            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.v("opendb", "FileNotFoundexeption: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v("opendb", "ioexeption: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.v("opendb", "Success!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

    }

    public SQLiteDatabase checkDB() { // this method helps to check whether the data base is exist or not 
        try {
            dbe = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(
                    "data/data/com.healthmonitor/databases/AuditDb.sqlite",
                    null, 0);
            Log.d("opendb", "EXIST");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("opendb", e.getMessage());
        }
        return dbe;
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase createOrOpenDB(String dbName) { // this method helps to check whether the data base is exist or not 
        try {
            System.out.println("comming4");
            if(!dbName.equals("")){
            dbe = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(
                    "data/data/com.healthmonitor/databases/"+dbName+".sqlite",
                    null,0);// it opens the exist database 
            System.out.println("comming5");

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("comming44");
            Log.d("opendb", e.getMessage());
            dbe = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(
                    "data/data/com.healthmonitor/databases/"+dbName+".sqlite",
                    null);// it creates the database if it does not exists
        }
        return dbe;
    }

}
```

### **Db adapter class**

```
public class DbAdapter {

    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_COMP_ID = "compID";
    public static final String KEY_DBASE = "dbase";
    public static final String KEY_DTABLE = "dtable";
    public static final String KEY_DTFITELD = "dtfield";
    public static final String KEY_ACTION = "action";
    public static final String KEY_ORIGINATION = "origination";
    public static final String KEY_TERMINATION = "termination";
    public static final String KEY_INDEX = "fieldIndex";
    private static final String TAG = "DbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private static SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HealthDb.sqlite";
    private static final String FTS_AUDIT_TABLE = "audit_table";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;// Version of sqlite database

    private static Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            DataBaseHelper cb = new DataBaseHelper(mCtx, mCtx.getPackageName());
            mDb = cb.checkDB();
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");

        }
    }

    public DbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public DbAdapter open() throws SQLException {

        DataBaseHelper cb = new DataBaseHelper(mCtx, mCtx.getPackageName());
        mDb = cb.checkDB();
        return this;
    }

    public DbAdapter createOrOpenDb(String dbName) throws SQLException {
        //system.out.println("comming3");
        if (!dbName.equals("")) {
            DataBaseHelper cb = new DataBaseHelper(mCtx, mCtx.getPackageName());
            mDb = cb.createOrOpenDB(dbName);
            //system.out.println("comming4");
            return this;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDb.close();
    }

    public void DatabaseAdd(String databaseName) {

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
                .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        //system.out.println("data is " + timeStamp);

        createOrOpenDb(databaseName);// creates the database with the specified
                                        // name

        open();
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();// Initializes the
                                                            // content value

        initialValues.put(KEY_DBASE, databaseName);

        initialValues.put(KEY_ACTION, "Database created");
        initialValues.put(KEY_ORIGINATION, timeStamp);

        long done = mDb.insert(FTS_AUDIT_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        //system.out.println("done " + done);

        String query = "UPDATE " + FTS_AUDIT_TABLE + " SET " + KEY_COMP_ID
                + "=(SELECT " + KEY_ID + " FROM " + FTS_AUDIT_TABLE + " WHERE "
                + KEY_ORIGINATION + " =" + timeStamp + ") WHERE "
                + KEY_ORIGINATION + " =" + timeStamp;
        mDb.execSQL(query);

        close();
    }

    public boolean DatabaseDelete(String databaseName) {

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
                .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        //system.out.println("time stamp in delete " + timeStamp);

        File file = new File("data/data/com.healthmonitor/databases/"
                + databaseName + ".sqlite");// selects the db file from the
                                            // system
        new File("data/data/com.healthmonitor/databases/" + databaseName
                + "-journal").delete();

        if (file.delete()) {
            open();

            String query2 = "UPDATE " + FTS_AUDIT_TABLE + " SET "
                    + KEY_TERMINATION + "='" + timeStamp + "' WHERE "
                    + KEY_DBASE + " = '" + databaseName + "' and "
                    + KEY_TERMINATION + " is null;";

            mDb.execSQL(query2);

            close();

            return true;

        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean DatabaseExistOrNot(String databaseName) {

        File file = new File("data/data/com.healthmonitor/databases/"
                + databaseName + ".sqlite");
        return file.exists();
    }

    public boolean DatabaseEdit(String oldDatabaseName, String newDatabseNAme) {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
                .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        File filefrom = new File("data/data/com.healthmonitor/databases/"
                + oldDatabaseName + ".sqlite");

        File fileto = new File("data/data/com.healthmonitor/databases/"
                + newDatabseNAme + ".sqlite");

        if (filefrom.renameTo(fileto)) {

            open();

            String query3 = "Select " + KEY_COMP_ID + "," + KEY_DTFITELD + ","
                    + KEY_INDEX + "," + KEY_TERMINATION + "," + KEY_DTABLE
                    + " from " + FTS_AUDIT_TABLE + " where " + KEY_DBASE
                    + "= '" + oldDatabaseName + "' and " + KEY_TERMINATION
                    + " is null";
            Cursor cursor1 = mDb.rawQuery(query3, null);

            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            if (cursor1 != null) {
                cursor1.moveToFirst();

                do {
                    initialValues.put(KEY_COMP_ID, cursor1.getString(0));
                    initialValues.put(KEY_DBASE, newDatabseNAme);
                    initialValues.put(KEY_DTABLE, cursor1.getString(4));
                    initialValues.put(KEY_DTFITELD, cursor1.getString(1));
                    initialValues.put(KEY_INDEX, cursor1.getString(2));
                    initialValues.put(KEY_ACTION, "Database is renamed from"
                            + oldDatabaseName);
                    initialValues.put(KEY_ORIGINATION, timeStamp);
                    initialValues.put(KEY_TERMINATION, cursor1.getString(3));
                    long done1 = mDb.insert(FTS_AUDIT_TABLE, null,
                            initialValues);

                } while (cursor1.moveToNext());

            }

            String query4 = "UPDATE " + FTS_AUDIT_TABLE + " SET "
                    + KEY_TERMINATION + "='" + timeStamp + "' WHERE "
                    + KEY_DBASE + " = '" + oldDatabaseName + "'";

            mDb.execSQL(query4);

            close();

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void TableAdd(String selectedDb, String Tablename) {

        DataBaseHelper cb = new DataBaseHelper(mCtx, mCtx.getPackageName());
        mDb = cb.createOrOpenDB(selectedDb);

        String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '" + Tablename
                + "' (_Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)";

        mDb.execSQL(query);

        mDb.close();
        open();
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
                .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

        initialValues.put(KEY_DBASE, selectedDb);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DTABLE, Tablename);
        initialValues.put(KEY_ACTION, "Table Created");
        initialValues.put(KEY_ORIGINATION, timeStamp);
        long done = mDb.insert(FTS_AUDIT_TABLE, null, initialValues);

        String query1 = "UPDATE " + FTS_AUDIT_TABLE + " SET " + KEY_COMP_ID
                + "=(SELECT " + KEY_ID + " FROM " + FTS_AUDIT_TABLE + " WHERE "
                + KEY_ORIGINATION + " =" + timeStamp + ") WHERE "
                + KEY_ORIGINATION + " =" + timeStamp;
        mDb.execSQL(query1);

        AddField(selectedDb, Tablename, "_Id", "Text", "NO");
        AddField(selectedDb, Tablename, "Orgination", "Text", "NO");
        AddField(selectedDb, Tablename, "Termination", "Text", "NO");
        close();

    }

    public Cursor TableNames(String selectedDb) {
        if (!selectedDb.equals("")) {

            DataBaseHelper cb = new DataBaseHelper(mCtx, mCtx.getPackageName());
            mDb = cb.createOrOpenDB(selectedDb);
            String query = "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'";
            Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            mDb.close();
            return cursor;
        }
        return null;

    }

    public boolean TableDelete(String selectedDb, String selectedTable) {

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
                .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        DataBaseHelper cb = new DataBaseHelper(mCtx, mCtx.getPackageName());
        mDb = cb.createOrOpenDB(selectedDb);
        String query = "Drop table '" + selectedTable + "'";

        mDb.execSQL(query);

        mDb.close();

        open();

        String query2 = "UPDATE " + FTS_AUDIT_TABLE + " SET " + KEY_TERMINATION
                + "='" + timeStamp + "' WHERE " + KEY_DBASE + " = '"
                + selectedDb + "' and " + KEY_DTABLE + " ='" + selectedTable
                + "' and " + KEY_TERMINATION + " is null";
        mDb.execSQL(query2);

        close();
        return true;

    }

    public void TableEdit(String selectedDb, String selectedTable,
            String newTableName) {

        DataBaseHelper cb = new DataBaseHelper(mCtx, mCtx.getPackageName());
        mDb = cb.createOrOpenDB(selectedDb);

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
                .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        try {
            String query = "ALTER TABLE '" + selectedTable + "' RENAME TO '"
                    + newTableName + "'";
            mDb.execSQL(query);

            mDb.close();
            open();

            String query3 = "Select " + KEY_COMP_ID + "," + KEY_DTFITELD + ","
                    + KEY_INDEX + "," + KEY_TERMINATION + " from "
                    + FTS_AUDIT_TABLE + " where " + KEY_DBASE + "= '"
                    + selectedDb + "' and " + KEY_DTABLE + "='" + selectedTable
                    + "' and " + KEY_TERMINATION + " is null";
            Cursor cursor1 = mDb.rawQuery(query3, null);

            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();// Initializes 

            if (cursor1 != null) {
                cursor1.moveToFirst();

                do {
                    initialValues.put(KEY_COMP_ID, cursor1.getString(0));
                    initialValues.put(KEY_DBASE, selectedDb);
                    initialValues.put(KEY_DTABLE, newTableName);
                    initialValues.put(KEY_DTFITELD, cursor1.getString(1));
                    initialValues.put(KEY_INDEX, cursor1.getString(2));
                    initialValues.put(KEY_ACTION, "Table is renamed from"
                            + selectedTable);
                    initialValues.put(KEY_ORIGINATION, timeStamp);
                    initialValues.put(KEY_TERMINATION, cursor1.getString(3));
                    long done1 = mDb.insert(FTS_AUDIT_TABLE, null,
                            initialValues);
                    //system.out.println("done " + done1);

                } while (cursor1.moveToNext());

            }

            String query4 = "UPDATE " + FTS_AUDIT_TABLE + " SET "
                    + KEY_TERMINATION + "='" + timeStamp + "' WHERE "
                    + KEY_DBASE + " = '" + selectedDb + "' and " + KEY_DTABLE
                    + " ='" + selectedTable + "' and " + KEY_TERMINATION
                    + " is null";
            //system.out.println("query4" + query4);

            mDb.execSQL(query4);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        close();
    }

    public Cursor TableView(String selectedDb, String selectedTable, int check) {

        Cursor cursor;

        if (!selectedTable.equals(FTS_AUDIT_TABLE)) {
            open();

            String query1 = "select  " + KEY_DTFITELD + " from "
                    + FTS_AUDIT_TABLE + " where " + KEY_DBASE + " = '"
                    + selectedDb + "' and " + KEY_DTABLE + " = '"
                    + selectedTable + "' and " + KEY_TERMINATION + " is null;";
            //system.out.println(query1);
            Cursor cursor1 = mDb.rawQuery(query1, null);
            String deletedField = "";
            try {
                if (cursor1 != null) {
                    cursor1.moveToFirst();

                    do {
                        if (cursor1.getString(cursor1
                                .getColumnIndex(DbAdapter.KEY_DTFITELD)) != null) {

                            deletedField = deletedField
                                    + cursor1
                                            .getString(cursor1
                                                    .getColumnIndex(DbAdapter.KEY_DTFITELD))
                                    + ",";
                        }

                    } while (cursor1.moveToNext());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            //system.out.println("not removed fields" + deletedField);
            close();
            DataBaseHelper cb = new DataBaseHelper(mCtx, mCtx.getPackageName());
            mDb = cb.createOrOpenDB(selectedDb);

            String query;
            if (check == 0) {
                query = "SELECT "
                        + deletedField.substring(0, deletedField.length() - 1)
                        + " FROM '" + selectedTable
                        + "' where Termination is null";
            } else {

                query = "SELECT "
                        + deletedField.substring(0, deletedField.length() - 1)
                        + " FROM '" + selectedTable + "'";
            }

            cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            mDb.close();
            return cursor;

        }

        else {
            if (check == 0) {
                DataBaseHelper cb = new DataBaseHelper(mCtx,
                        mCtx.getPackageName());
                mDb = cb.createOrOpenDB(selectedDb);
                String query = "SELECT * FROM '" + selectedTable + "' where "
                        + KEY_TERMINATION + " is null";

                cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                }
                mDb.close();
                return cursor;
            } else {
                DataBaseHelper cb = new DataBaseHelper(mCtx,
                        mCtx.getPackageName());
                mDb = cb.createOrOpenDB(selectedDb);
                String query = "SELECT * FROM '" + selectedTable + "'";
                cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                }
                mDb.close();
                return cursor;

            }
        }

    }

    public void DeleteRow(String selectedDb, String selectedTable, String rowid) {

        DataBaseHelper cb = new DataBaseHelper(mCtx, mCtx.getPackageName());
        mDb = cb.createOrOpenDB(selectedDb);

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
                .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        String query2 = "UPDATE " + selectedTable + " SET " + "Termination = '"
                + timeStamp + "' where _Id =" + Integer.parseInt(rowid);

        mDb.execSQL(query2);
        mDb.close();

    }

    public boolean AddRow(String selectedDb, String selectedTable,
            String[] fieldvalue, Cursor cursor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        DataBaseHelper cb = new DataBaseHelper(mCtx, mCtx.getPackageName());
        mDb = cb.createOrOpenDB(selectedDb);

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
                .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        String columnname="Orgination";
        String values="'"+timeStamp+"'";

        for (int i = 3; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {

            fieldvalue[i]);

            columnname=columnname+","+cursor.getColumnName(i);
            values=values+",'"+fieldvalue[i]+"'";

        }

        String query="INSERT INTO "+selectedTable+" ("+columnname+") VALUES ("+values+")"; 

            try {
                mDb.execSQL(query);
                mDb.close();
                return true;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                mDb.close();
                return false;
            }                                                       
    }

    public boolean EditRow(String selectedDb, String selectedTable,
            String[] fieldvalue, Cursor cursor, String selectedRowId) {

        DataBaseHelper cb = new DataBaseHelper(mCtx, mCtx.getPackageName());
        mDb = cb.createOrOpenDB(selectedDb);

        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        for (int i = 3; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {

            initialValues.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), fieldvalue[i]);
        }

        long done = mDb.update(selectedTable, initialValues,
                cursor.getColumnName(0) + "=" + selectedRowId, null);

        mDb.close();
        if (done != -1)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public Cursor TableValues(String selectedDb, String selectedTable) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DataBaseHelper cb = new DataBaseHelper(mCtx, mCtx.getPackageName());
        mDb = cb.createOrOpenDB(selectedDb);

        String query = "PRAGMA table_info ('" + selectedTable + "')";

        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        mDb.close();
        return cursor;

    }

    public boolean AddField(String selectedDb, String selectedTable,
            String fieldName, String fieldType, String index) {

        try {
            DataBaseHelper cb = new DataBaseHelper(mCtx, mCtx.getPackageName());

        if (!fieldName.equals("_Id")) {
                mDb = cb.createOrOpenDB(selectedDb);
                String query = "ALTER TABLE '" + selectedTable
                        + "' ADD COLUMN '" + fieldName + "' '" + fieldType
                        + "';";

                mDb.execSQL(query);

                mDb.close();
            }
            open();

            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
                    .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            //system.out.println("data is " + timeStamp);

            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();// Initializes

            initialValues.put(KEY_DBASE, selectedDb);
            initialValues.put(KEY_DTABLE, selectedTable);
            initialValues.put(KEY_DTFITELD, fieldName);
            initialValues.put(KEY_ACTION, "field is created ");
            initialValues.put(KEY_ORIGINATION, timeStamp);
            initialValues.put(KEY_INDEX, index);

            long done = mDb.insert(FTS_AUDIT_TABLE, null, initialValues);
            //system.out.println("done " + done);

            String query2 = "UPDATE " + FTS_AUDIT_TABLE + " SET " + KEY_COMP_ID
                    + "=(SELECT " + KEY_ID + " FROM " + FTS_AUDIT_TABLE
                    + " WHERE " + KEY_ORIGINATION + " ='" + timeStamp
                    + "' ORDER BY " + KEY_ID + " DESC) WHERE "
                    + KEY_ORIGINATION + " ='" + timeStamp + "' and "
                    + KEY_DTFITELD + "='" + fieldName + "' ;";
            mDb.execSQL(query2);

            close();
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }

    public Cursor IndexValues(String selectedDb, String selectedTable) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DataBaseHelper cb = new DataBaseHelper(mCtx, mCtx.getPackageName());
        try {
            open();

            String query = "select " + KEY_DTFITELD + "," + KEY_INDEX
                    + " from " + FTS_AUDIT_TABLE + " where " + KEY_DBASE + "='"
                    + selectedDb + "' and " + KEY_DTABLE + " ='"
                    + selectedTable + "' and " + KEY_DTFITELD
                    + " not NULL and " + KEY_TERMINATION + " is null";
            //system.out.println(query);
            Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, null);

            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
            }

            return cursor;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        close();
        return null;

    }

    public boolean DeleteField(String selectedDb, String selectedTable,
            String fieldName) {

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
                .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        //system.out.println("data is " + timeStamp);
        open();

        try {
            String query1 = "UPDATE " + FTS_AUDIT_TABLE + " SET "
                    + KEY_TERMINATION + "='" + timeStamp + "' where "
                    + KEY_DBASE + "='" + selectedDb + "' and " + KEY_DTABLE
                    + "='" + selectedTable + "' and " + KEY_DTFITELD + "='"
                    + fieldName + "' and " + KEY_TERMINATION + " is null;";
            //system.out.println(query1);

            mDb.execSQL(query1);
            mDb.close();


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        close();

        return true;

    }

    public String GetDeleteField(String selectedDb, String selectedTable) {

        open();

        String query1 = "select  " + KEY_DTFITELD + " from " + FTS_AUDIT_TABLE
                + " where " + KEY_DBASE + " = '" + selectedDb + "' and "
                + KEY_DTABLE + " = '" + selectedTable + "' and "
                + KEY_TERMINATION + " not null and " + KEY_ID + ">= (Select "
                + KEY_ID + " from " + FTS_AUDIT_TABLE + "  where " + KEY_DBASE
                + " = '" + selectedDb + "' and " + KEY_DTABLE + " = '"
                + selectedTable + "' and " + KEY_TERMINATION
                + " is null Order By " + KEY_ID + " desc );";
        //system.out.println(query1);

        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query1, null);

        String deletedField = "";
        try {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                do {

                    deletedField = deletedField
                            + cursor.getString(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(DbAdapter.KEY_DTFITELD));

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        close();

        //system.out.println("deleted fields" + deletedField);



        return deletedField;

    }

    public boolean EditField(String selectedDb, String selectedTable,
            String OldfieldName, String NewfieldName, String fieldType,
            String index) {

        try {

            DeleteField(selectedDb, selectedTable, OldfieldName);

            DataBaseHelper cb = new DataBaseHelper(mCtx, mCtx.getPackageName());
            mDb = cb.createOrOpenDB(selectedDb);

            String query = "ALTER TABLE '" + selectedTable + "' ADD COLUMN '"
                    + NewfieldName + "' '" + fieldType + "';";

            mDb.execSQL(query);

            mDb.close();

            open();

            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
                    .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();// Initializes

            initialValues.put(KEY_DBASE, selectedDb);
            initialValues.put(KEY_DTABLE, selectedTable);
            initialValues.put(KEY_DTFITELD, NewfieldName);
            initialValues.put(KEY_ACTION, "field is Edited from "
                    + OldfieldName);
            initialValues.put(KEY_ORIGINATION, timeStamp);
            initialValues.put(KEY_INDEX, index);

            long done = mDb.insert(FTS_AUDIT_TABLE, null, initialValues);
            //system.out.println("done " + done);

            String query2 = "UPDATE " + FTS_AUDIT_TABLE + " SET " + KEY_COMP_ID
                    + "=(SELECT " + KEY_COMP_ID + " FROM " + FTS_AUDIT_TABLE
                    + " WHERE " + KEY_DTFITELD + " ='" + OldfieldName
                    + "' ORDER BY " + KEY_ID + " DESC) WHERE "
                    + KEY_ORIGINATION + " ='" + timeStamp + "' and "
                    + KEY_DTFITELD + "='" + NewfieldName + "' ;";
            mDb.execSQL(query2);

            close();
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

I am using **"AddRow"** method to add the values

Comment: Please be clear about your question, what is your problem?

Comment: Please post your logs if it is throwing an error. or maybe data is inserting correctly and your are not retrieving it ?

Comment: Why are you executing an SQL query that way, it seems that you would benefit JUST fine from executing queries via the wrapped methods... Something to consider. Also if you have a problem <b>Post the stacktrace!!!</b>

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might be running into permissions errors or path errors.  Not enough information to determine what the actual issue is.  But I'm surprised you are creating your sqlite files manually.  Android provides Sqlite databases almost like a "service" where you do not have to deal with the complexity of managing files.

Check out this tutorial:  http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

SqliteOpenHelper should be all you need and you should not be reaching out to db files unless you're trying to do something SqliteOpenHelper doesn't support (which doesn't seem like the case).

You can create a specialized version of SqliteOpenHelper for each Sqlite database you need OR you can try to create a single one that manages all databases (although it'll be much more complex and not recommended).

edit:  Oh, and if you're looking to install a prepopulated sqlite database, see this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/620086/2848773

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong by creating your sqlite database files manually and also by trying to specify the path for the Database. You should leave this to be handled by the SQLite helper class.It is also not advisable to query your database the way you are doing using raw sql query,please use the sqlitedatabase.query() method instead.In case you run into trouble you can consult me.Please have a look at this class example:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

// Database name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "stocktrader.db";

// Database tables
private static final String TABLE_SHARES = "Shares";
private static final String TABLE_ALERTS = "Alerts";
private static final String TABLE_TASKS = "Tasks";
private static final String TABLE_MESSAGES = "Messages";

// Shares table columns
private static final String KEY_NAME = "share_name";
private static final String KEY_PRICE = "share_price";
private static final String KEY_YESTERDAY = "share_yesterday_price";
private static final String KEY_CASH_CHANGE = "share_cash_change";
private static final String KEY_PERCENTAGE_CHANGE = "share_percentage_change";

// alerts table columns
private static final String KEY_SHARE_NAME = "share_name";
private static final String KEY_MIN_PRICE = "min_price";
private static final String KEY_MAX_PRICE = "max_price";
private static final String KEY_ACTION = "action";
private static final String KEY_USER = "user";

// tasks table columns
private static final String KEY_SHARENAME = "share_name";
private static final String KEY_TASK = "task";
private static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "message";
private static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";

// Messages table columns
private static final String KEY_HEADER = "title";
private static final String KEY_BODY = "message";
// private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
private static final String KEY_ID = "message_id";
private static final String KEY_USER_ID = "user";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

String CREATE_TABLE_SHARES = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SHARES + "("
        + KEY_NAME + " text primary key not null, " + KEY_PRICE
        + " double not null, " + KEY_YESTERDAY + " double, "
        + KEY_CASH_CHANGE + " double, " + KEY_PERCENTAGE_CHANGE
        + " double);";

String CREATE_TABLE_ALERTS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ALERTS + "("
        + KEY_SHARE_NAME + " text primary key not null," + KEY_MIN_PRICE
        + " double default null," + KEY_MAX_PRICE + " double default null,"
        + KEY_USER + " text not null," + KEY_ACTION + " int not null);";

String CREATE_TABLE_TASKS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TASKS + "("
        + KEY_SHARENAME + " text primary key not null," + KEY_TASK
        + " int not null," + KEY_MESSAGE + " text null," + KEY_STATUS
        + " int not null);";

String CREATE_TABLE_MESSAGES = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MESSAGES + "("
        + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement," + KEY_HEADER
        + " text not null," + KEY_BODY + " text not null," + KEY_USER_ID
        + " text not null);";

// Creating tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SHARES);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ALERTS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TASKS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MESSAGES);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(DatabaseHandler.class.getName(), "Upgrading from " + oldVersion
            + " to " + newVersion + ". All data will be lost.");

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SHARES);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ALERTS);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MESSAGES);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TASKS);

    // create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addShares(ArrayList<SharePrices> shares) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    String share_name;
    double share_price;
    double yesterday_price;
    for (int i = 0; i < shares.size(); i++) {
        try {
            Cursor cursor = null;
            share_name = shares.get(i).getName();
            share_price = Double.parseDouble(shares.get(i).getPrice());
            yesterday_price = Double.parseDouble(shares.get(i)
                    .getYesterdays());
            values.put(KEY_NAME, share_name);
            values.put(KEY_PRICE, share_price);
            values.put(KEY_YESTERDAY, yesterday_price);
            values.put(
                    KEY_CASH_CHANGE,
                    Math.round((share_price - yesterday_price) * 100.0) / 100.0);
            if (yesterday_price == 0) {
                values.put(KEY_PERCENTAGE_CHANGE, "100");
            } else {
                values.put(
                        KEY_PERCENTAGE_CHANGE,
                        Math.round((((share_price - yesterday_price) / yesterday_price) * 100) * 100.0) / 100.0);
            }
            cursor = database.query(TABLE_SHARES,
                    new String[] { KEY_NAME }, KEY_NAME + "=?",
                    new String[] { share_name }, null, null, null, null);

            if (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
                database.update(TABLE_SHARES, values, KEY_NAME + "=?",
                        new String[] { share_name });

                Log.i("db", "updated");
            } else {
                database.insert(TABLE_SHARES, null, values);

                Log.i("db", "inserted");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    database.close();
}

public void addToWatchList(String share_name, double max_price,
        double min_price, int action, String user) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = database.query(TABLE_ALERTS,
                new String[] { KEY_SHARE_NAME }, KEY_SHARE_NAME + "=? AND "
                        + KEY_USER + "=?",
                new String[] { share_name, user }, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
            if (max_price == 0.0) {
                values.put(KEY_SHARE_NAME, share_name);
                values.put(KEY_MIN_PRICE, min_price);
                values.put(KEY_ACTION, action);
                values.put(KEY_USER, user);
                database.update(TABLE_ALERTS, values, KEY_SHARE_NAME
                        + "=? AND " + KEY_USER + "=?", new String[] {
                        share_name, user });
            } else if (min_price == 0.0) {
                values.put(KEY_SHARE_NAME, share_name);
                values.put(KEY_MAX_PRICE, max_price);
                values.put(KEY_ACTION, action);
                values.put(KEY_USER, user);
                database.update(TABLE_ALERTS, values, KEY_SHARE_NAME
                        + "=? AND " + KEY_USER + "=?", new String[] {
                        share_name, user });
            }

            else {
                values.put(KEY_SHARE_NAME, share_name);
                values.put(KEY_MAX_PRICE, max_price);
                values.put(KEY_MIN_PRICE, min_price);
                values.put(KEY_ACTION, action);
                values.put(KEY_USER, user);
                database.insert(TABLE_ALERTS, null, values);
                database.update(TABLE_ALERTS, values, KEY_SHARE_NAME
                        + "=? AND " + KEY_USER + "=?", new String[] {
                        share_name, user });
            }
        } else {
            if (max_price == 0.0) {
                values.put(KEY_SHARE_NAME, share_name);
                values.put(KEY_MIN_PRICE, min_price);
                values.put(KEY_ACTION, action);
                values.put(KEY_USER, user);
                database.insert(TABLE_ALERTS, null, values);
            } else if (min_price == 0.0) {
                values.put(KEY_SHARE_NAME, share_name);
                values.put(KEY_MAX_PRICE, max_price);
                values.put(KEY_ACTION, action);
                values.put(KEY_USER, user);
                database.insert(TABLE_ALERTS, null, values);
            }

            else {
                values.put(KEY_SHARE_NAME, share_name);
                values.put(KEY_MAX_PRICE, max_price);
                values.put(KEY_MIN_PRICE, min_price);
                values.put(KEY_ACTION, action);
                values.put(KEY_USER, user);
                database.insert(TABLE_ALERTS, null, values);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    database.close();
}

public void addMessage(String message, String header, String user) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_HEADER, header);
    values.put(KEY_BODY, message);
    values.put(KEY_USER_ID, user);
    try {
        database.insert(TABLE_MESSAGES, null, values);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    database.close();
}

public Cursor getMessageHeaders(String user) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = database.query(TABLE_MESSAGES, null, KEY_USER_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { user }, null, null, null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cursor;
}


public void deleteMessage(String message_id) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        database.delete(TABLE_MESSAGES, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { message_id });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    database.close();
}
```

}